# How to pronounce subreddit names?

Tags: pronunciation, terminology, slang, internet

I'm unsure of how to pronounce subreddit names in casual conversation without preface. I read `/r/funny` mentally as "R funny", but this doesn't always work in conversation, especially with acronym subreddits, like `/r/wtf`, as the 'r' could be misinterpreted as part of the subreddit name.

Furthermore, it can be sometimes hard to assume that one is referring to a subreddit  if no context is given. For example,

> I saw the weirdest thing this morning on `/r/wtf`.

can be hard to interpret if read aloud in the manner mentioned above.

Comment: "I saw the weirdest thing this morning on Reddit."

Comment: This is a problem that comes up whenever an incomprehensible code is shared among a speech (or more likely, chat) community, but rarely actually spoken aloud. Not all TLAs are destined for phonetics. I've experienced this since the 1980s with numerous online groups that never thought about their own pronunciation until they were confronted with other people's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate word from Reddit-specific vocabulary that you're looking for is actually in your post, "subreddit":

> I saw this amazing photo on the earthporn subreddit.

More informally, if it's clear that it's Reddit that you're talking about, "sub" is less of a mouthful:

> Do you remember that thing with the wire that showed up in the lifehacks sub last week?

In your example, it would be something like:

> I saw the weirdest thing this morning on the what-the-f sub.